# CRM Late Bound - Cleaner Approach

Tags: console-application, dynamics-crm-2013

I have the following code and I'm trying to find a more elegant approach to this. activityParty is a DataCollection. I am basically trying to get a list of recipients for an email, which can be of type users or contacts.

I am familiar with early bound but in this scenario must use late bound.

Is there a better approach to this?

```cs
var recipientParty = activityParty.Where(x => x.GetAliasedValueOrDefault<OptionSetValue>("ap.participationtypemask").Value == 2).ToList();
var recipientList = new List<string>();

foreach (var to in recipientParty)
{
    if (to.Attributes.Contains("u.internalemailaddress"))
    {
        recipientList.Add(to.GetAliasedValueOrDefault<string>("u.internalemailaddress"));
    }

    if (to.Attributes.Contains("c.emailaddress1"))
    {
        recipientList.Add(to.GetAliasedValueOrDefault<string>("c.emailaddress1"));
    }
}
```

Comment: check if this can help http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/09/getattributevalue-activityparty.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `AddressUsed` property of `ActivityParty` entity. It should contain email address, regardless which entity is source of party involved.

So, in your code you can use `to.AddressUsed`  instead whole if {...} statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
using (var serviceContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(this.OrganizationService)) // if you are writing custom code activity
//using (var serviceContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(localContext.OrganizationService)) // if you are writing plugin
{
    var activityPartySet = serviceContext.CreateQuery<ActivityParty>();
    var activityParties = activityPartySet.Where(
                                ap => ap.PartyId != null && 
                                ap.ParticipationTypeMask != null && 
                                ap.ParticipationTypeMask.Value == 2).ToList();

    var userSet = serviceContext.CreateQuery<SystemUser>();
    var contactSet = serviceContext.CreateQuery<Contact>();
    var recipientList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var ap in activityParties)
    {
        var partyRef = ap.PartyId;
        if (partyRef.LogicalName == SystemUser.EntityLogicalName)
        {
            var user = (from u in userSet
                        where u.Id == partyRef.Id
                        select new SystemUser
                        {
                            InternalEMailAddress = u.InternalEMailAddress
                        }).FirstOrDefault();

            if (user != null)
                recipientList.Add(user.InternalEMailAddress);
        }
        else if (partyRef.LogicalName == Contact.EntityLogicalName)
        {
            var contact = (from c in contactSet
                           where c.Id == partyRef.Id
                           select new Contact
                           {
                                EMailAddress1 = c.EMailAddress1
                           }).FirstOrDefault();

             if (contact != null)
                 recipientList.Add(contact.EMailAddress1);
         }
     }
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am using Late Bound